# Stubbing multiple requests to the same uri

Tags: rspec, webmock

I would like to use the same uri with different request params, how can I do this?
The following example seems does not work (

```
  stub_request(:post, "http://tests/1/users/create").
      with({email: 'wrong_format'}).
      to_return(status: 400, body: {msg: 'Bad request'}.to_json, headers: {})

  stub_request(:post, "http://tests/1/users/create").
      with(email: "test@mail.com").
      to_return(status: 200, body: {msg: 'Thanks for signing up for us'}.to_json, headers: {})
```

Answer (score 0):

From what the documentation says, the with-clauses are not correct (you should use `body: { email: "foo@bar.de" }` or something similar).

[Docs here!](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-request-body-against-a-hash-body-can-be-url-encoded-json-or-xml)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#multiple-responses-for-repeated-requests), this is accomplished by adding a sequence of return hashes:

```
stub_request(:get, "www.example.com").
  to_return({body: "abc"}, {body: "def"})
Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/')    # ===> "abc\n"
Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/')    # ===> "def\n"
```